# Some titles cause links to break

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

In documentation, some titles can cause links to fail. I've only noticed this on example titles so far and haven't had the opportunity to try it with topic titles.

For example in the "Comments" topic of the C tag documentation https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/10670/comment there is an example named "//" (because C has two types of comments, neither of which is actually given a name by the standard AFAIK). The link to the example, seen by clicking on the example heading is `https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/10670/comments/32013/%2f%2f` which, in Google Chrome at least, results in an agent error for too many redirects.

Comment: They're often called "single line" and "multi-line" comments. But I don't think these names appear in the standard, either.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm on Win10, seeing this in Chrome and Edge, simply by clicking on the example heading - no copy & paste involved. Also seeing hte same error in chrome on Android 7.1.1

Comment: `/* */` is called a C-style or C89 comment, because this was the only form of comment in the original spec. `//` is usually called C++-style or new-style comments because it was introduced and popularised by C++, and added to a later C standard. @CodyGray has the colloquial names right though

Comment: @Toby I see it too, when clicking the section header for `//`, Chromium on Linux

Comment: Oh, never mind about not reproducing this without a copy-paste of the link. I was using the "Topic Outline" feature on the right. It in ever even occurred to me to click on the headings themselves.

Comment: @cat - Thanks. I am aware of how they are colloquially referred (your terms are colloquial also I think), but the standard does not provide names. Further, providing documentation for a C thing by saying "the thing from another language" seems to be a bit ...unhelpful to people that don't already know about the history of C. Also, (although, I know it is the convention) "multi-line" also seems to be redundant when being precise, because `/* ... */` can be either multi- or single line

Comment: Clicking on the example heading (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/10670/comments/32013/%2f%2f) in Firefox 54.0.1 on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.5, I get the 'problem loading page' message.  Clicking on the link in the topic outline (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/10670/comments/32013/%2f%2f#t=201707040721498041067) works fine.

Comment: From the C spec in the index, I think the most "standard" way of referring to them is // delimited comments and /* */ delimited comments. I.e. the two ways of commenting are referred to by their delimiters rather than by names.

Comment: @mydogisbox Thanks! That's pretty good and it fixes the immediate issue :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.

For SEO reasons we try and include the title in the url of a question, topic, or example and redirect to the canonical url when the title is mismatched.  We strip out a bunch of special characters for technical reasons.  In addition, there was some code that was being too clever when dealing with topic and example titles.

Now we'll just use `topic` or `example` as the title in the url if there are no "friendly" characters to include.